# Iterate nested array of object and display in html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a below `input` with nested array of objects.

`summary` is parent array of objects and `run_type` is nested one.

```
let input = {
      "summary": [
          {
              "name": "Release",
              "run_type": [
                {
                  "environment": "6nc",
                  "type": "QA1"
                },
                {
                  "environment": "3nc",
                  "type": "QA2"
                }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

I want to display a table like this. `Name` field has `rowspan` of 2 since there are 2 `run_type` for each `summary`

```
------------------------------------
   Name    | Environment | RunType |
------------------------------------
  Release  |     6nc     |  QA1    |
           |     3nc     |  QA2    |
------------------------------------
```

To display a table like this statically, i can do this way

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Vertical</th>
      <th>Environment</th>
      <th>RunType</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Release</td>
    <td>6nc</td>
    <td>QA1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3nc</td>
   <td>QA2</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

can someone please let me know how to dynamically show this table. I tried using this way but was unsuccessful.  the problem is that i am able to rowspan Name column into 2 rows but all other columns are not being placed as two rows within that same Name section

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Vertical</th>
      <th>Environment</th>
      <th>RunType</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {input?.summary?.map((project, indx) => {
       return (
         <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">{project?.name}</td>
             {project?.run_type?.map((runType, indx) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <td>{runType.environment}</td>
                    <td>{runType.type}</td>
                  </>
                );
             })}
         </tr>
       );
     })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Typo?  In the callback to `.map()` each record is called `project` but you're trying to use something called `summary`.  (Which *should* be producing an error, since that variable doesn't exist.)

Comment: @David- my bad, updated the correct syntax

Comment: And have you re-tested since making that change?  What specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: yes, retested it. the problem is that i am able to rowspan `Name` column into 2 rows but all other columns are not being placed as two rows within that same `Name` section

Comment: What is `vertical_name`?

Comment: @trincot- can you pls refresh. correct code is updated

Comment: Seems like you will need to place some more `<tr>` tags if you need the other columns in separate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you're using a single `<tr>` element to iterate through both the `run_type` environments and types. This leads to an incorrect rendering of the table structure.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
  <tbody>
    {input?.summary?.map((project, projectIndex) => (
      <>
        {project?.run_type?.map((runType, runTypeIndex) => (
          <tr key={`${projectIndex}-${runTypeIndex}`}>
            {runTypeIndex === 0 ? (
              <td rowspan={project.run_type.length}>{project.name}</td>
            ) : null}
            <td>{runType.environment}</td>
            <td>{runType.type}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </>
    ))}
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks @iChelsi for explaination. this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `<tr>` per `run_type`, so the inner loop should generate the `<tr>`, not the outer. As the `<td>` with rowspan should only be created for the first row of the project, use a conditional expression with `indx==0` to generate it:

```
input.summary?.map((project) =>
    project.run_type?.map((runType, indx, {length}) =>
        <tr>
           {indx == 0 ? <td rowspan={length}>{project.name}</td> : ''}
           <td>{runType.environment}</td>
           <td>{runType.type}</td>
        </tr>
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would transform the data into a matrix of text and row-span information first.

Now you can use the matrix to just render the `<tbody>`.

```js
let input = {
  "summary": [{
    "name": "Release",
    "run_type": [{
      "environment": "6nc",
      "type": "QA1"
    }, {
      "environment": "3nc",
      "type": "QA2"
    }]
  }]
};

const tableData = input.summary.flatMap(({ name, run_type }) => {
  return run_type.map(({ environment, type }, index) => {
    const row = [];
    if (index === 0) {
      row.push({ text: name, rowSpan: run_type.length });
    }
    row.push({ text: environment });
    row.push({ text: type });
    return row;
  });
});

document.querySelector('.data tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
  ${tableData.map(row =>
    `<tr>${row.map(col =>
      `<td rowSpan=${col.rowSpan ?? 1}>${col.text}</td>`)
    .join('')}</tr>`)
  .join('')}
`);
```

```css
table.data {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.data, .data th, .data td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.data th, .data td {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.data th {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

```html
<table class="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Environment</th>
      <th>RunType</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```